# Get the position of Selected Item in Action Mode

Tags: android, listview, position, multichoiceitems

When i long press any item in the list view then Contextual action bar showed. Now what i want that when i press the delete button after selecting items then the selected items get deleted but I am unable to get the position of selected items.
My code for multi choice mode is:

```
listViewMessages.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
listViewMessages.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                      long id, boolean checked) {
       mode.setTitle(listViewMessages.getCheckedItemCount()+ " Selected");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu:
                deleteScreenedMessageFromInbox();                                       
                  mode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu for the CAB
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

When i click on delete button then this method is calling:

```
deleteScreenedMessageFromInbox();
```

and i have to pass an argument in this method which is the position of selected items. Code for this method is:

```
public void deleteScreenedMessageFromInbox(Integer position) {

Integer id = smsIDs.get(position);

String deleteScreenedMessage = "delete from " + "sms" + " where " + "id" + " = " + id;

DBsms smsDb = new DBsms(this);
SQLiteDatabase dbw = smsDb.getWritableDatabase();
dbw.execSQL(deleteScreenedMessage);
dbw.close();
```

any solutions for this?

Comment: You could keep an `ArrayList<Integer>` outside the `MultiChoiceModeListener` and `add` an item or `remove` an item from the `ArrayList` from inside `onItemCheckedStateChanged` depending on whether `boolean checked` is true or false respectively. Let me know if you want me to expand this into an answer.

Comment: Yes please provide me sample code as i am confused a bit

Comment: I have made some modifications to your existing code and posted that as an answer. Please check.

Comment: Ok sir lemme check and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest:

```
List<Integer> positionsList = new ArrayList<>();//declare this as a member variable--outside of any method
listViewMessages.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
listViewMessages.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                  long id, boolean checked) {
   mode.setTitle(listViewMessages.getCheckedItemCount()+ " Selected");
   if(checked)
       positionsList.add(position)
   else
       positionsList.remove(position)
}

@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu:
            deleteScreenedMessageFromInbox();                                       
              mode.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu for the CAB
    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return false;
}
});
```

Then on your `deleteScreenedMessageFromInbox()` access `positionsList` like so:

```
public void deleteScreenedMessageFromInbox() {

    DBsms smsDb = new DBsms(this);
    SQLiteDatabase dbw = smsDb.getWritableDatabase();

    for(int position : positionsList) {
        Integer id = smsIDs.get(position);

        String deleteScreenedMessage = "delete from " + "sms" + " where " + "id" + " = " + id;
        dbw.execSQL(deleteScreenedMessage);
    }
    dbw.close();
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

implement the onitemclickListener and get the item id and save it in any variable and delete the item whenever user click on delete and next call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

for example

```
listViewMessages.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                            long arg3) {
        //you can pass position from here to your method like this
         deleteScreenedMessageFromInbox(position)


        String value = (String) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
        adapter.remove(value);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();               
    }
});
```

Comment: I have to pass an integer argument to my method.
what do i write in the action mode? how i pass value to that method

Comment: Not working . Nothing happened when i clicked the delete button

Comment: Use log or Toast to check if onitemclickListener is giving  your desired position value or not..